# How to configure signed SSL certificates with aspnet core 3.1 on hosted in Kestrel/linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, ssl, web-hosting

I managed to get a letsencrypt signed certificate to enable SSL for my domain on the host properly. Now I do not understand how to bind it to my application running on ubuntu:

I used the following to set-up the private key:

```
webBuilder.UseKestrel((hostingContext, options) =>
{
   options.ListenAnyIP(443, loptions => loptions.UseHttps("/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem"));
});
```

> The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key

It is not clear to me how to bind the public and private keys and use it remotely without the use of apache or nginx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to convert your **private key** and **certifcate** to pfx certificate using **OpenSSL** :

> openssl pkcs12 -inkey privatekey.pem -in mycert.cert -export -out mycertificate.pfx

Then, you can use it this way in your **appsettings.json** file for Kestrel :

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "HttpsDefaultCert": {
        "Url": "https://*:443"
      },
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:80"
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "mycertificate.pfx",
        "Password": "MyCertificatePassword"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Gambi! Works well

Comment: Can you help me please where should I put pfx file? @ThomasBones

Comment: On the exemple above, the certificate is placed in the same folder as the executable of your application (because the path is relative in my example).